# How to calculate sample variance?

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I have an infinite population. Out of this population, I'm picking $N=40$ items, each of which can have a value of $0$ or $1$. Say I get a mean of $0.7$. How do I calculate the standard error of this value?

I got the formula $$\sqrt{\frac{(1-\hat{p})(\hat{p})}{N}} = \sqrt{\frac{(1-0.7)(0.7)}{40}}$$ for the variance. However, this doesn't seem to make much sense when $\hat{p}$ is $0$, because then even for a very small sample I get a variance of $0$. So, I wonder if I'm using the right formula, and if the above formula is an approximation of some sort.

Comment: The formula you quote is for standard deviation, also sometimes known as standard error.  There is no issue if $\hat{p}=0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas say N=1 and I take one sample which has value of 0. in that case $\hat{p} = 0$ , and the standard deviation is 0 too. Does that make sense? I would expect standard deviation that is much higher. Maybe you can explain a bit more?

Comment: If you take a sample of $1$, there is not going to be any wiggling. So of course the SD is $0$. Any small sample makes the sample variance a very poor estimator of the population variance, perhaps that is what is guiding your intuition.